# Замена надписей в v-date-picker на Vuetify JS

Tags: vue.js, datepicker, vuetify, customview

Имеется обычный DatePicker из Vuetify, у которого установлено locale="ru-RU".

Но дни недели выводятся сокращением в одну буквы "П, В, С...". Каким образом я могу получить сокращение в две буквы "Пн, Вт, Ср....."?

Также надо вместо 2 selected вывести две выбранные даты, как она выводиться без пропса "range". В документации не нашел под это дело не пропсов, не слотом.

```
<v-date-picker
    v-model="date"
    range
    scrollable
    locale="ru-RU"
    first-day-of-week=1
></v-date-picker>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У `DatePicker` есть реквизит `weekday-format` для доступа к дням недели:

```
Name: weekday-format
Type: function
Default: null
Description: Allows you to customize the format of the weekday string that appears in the body of the calendar. Called with date (ISO 8601 date string) arguments.
```

Т.е., если дообавить `:weekday-format` в `v-date-picker`, например так:

```js
<v-date-picker
    v-model="date"
    locale="ru-ru"
    :weekday-format="getCustomDay"
></v-date-picker>
```

и в `methods` скрипт:

```js
getCustomDay(date){
    const daysOfWeek = ['Пн', 'Вт', 'Ср', 'Чт', 'Пт', 'Сб', 'Вс'];
    let i = new Date(date).getDay(date)
    return daysOfWeek[i]
},
```

то в заголовке недели `DatePicker`-a получиться "Пн, Вт, Ср ... Вс".